# Windows 7 Explorer.exe

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

I want to extend Windows 7 Explorer.exe (32/64 bits) where does one start? I want to modify UI adding new menu items and perhaps add new windows directly inside of current window. Is it related to "Basic Folder Object Interfaces"? Any help URLs, Books anything appeciated!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguideindex.aspx

If you don't like that ATL (or even C++) stuff, you can combine it with:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_in_c1.aspx

Comment: Despite the name, no offense intended. ;)

Comment: Yes, dumb name but the intro is good.  Its dated but this stuff hasn't fundamentally changed at all in the past 3 Windows versions.  Other than the VS versions.

Comment: The stuff on adding columns *has* changed, FWIW, although it still applies to several 3rd party file managers which didn't inexplicably drop the old, useful interfaces like Explorer did (removing useful features of things like TortoiseSVN in the process).